# nameserver problems with webmin/virtualmin

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, nameserver

*[I've also asked this in Webmasters - it seems to fall into a grey area between here and there]*

I'm setting up a shiny new vps with my own nameserver. Fortunately I had a spare domain that I'm using and have registered as a nameserver.

After a struggle, I seem to have it working but when I check two test sites with intoDNS, one appears to work and the other doesn't.

With dig, neither work. The setup for the two is identical other than one being hosted with namecheap and the other with dataflame.co.uk.

The urls are:

1. http://zzokk.com
2. http://leoponton.org

The nameserver entries for the two sites were repointed 48 hours ago.

I can't figure out what the problem is. Anybody got any ideas?

This is the records file for the nameserver:

```
    $ttl 38400

    woopeedoo.net.  IN  SOA ns1.woopeedoo.net. xxx.gmail.com. (

                1356196970
                30M
                3600
                604800
                38400 )

woopeedoo.net.  IN  NS  ns1.woopeedoo.net.
woopeedoo.net.  IN  NS  ns2.woopeedoo.net.
ns1.woopeedoo.net.  IN  A   xx.yyy.181.221
ns2.woopeedoo.net.  IN  A   xx.yyy.181.221
woopeedoo.net.  IN  A   127.0.0.2
m.woopeedoo.net.woopeedoo.net.  IN  A   127.0.0.2
woopeedoo.net.  IN  MX  5 mail.woopeedoo.net.
mail.woopeedoo.net. IN  A   127.0.0.2
localhost.woopeedoo.net.    IN  A   127.0.0.1
xx.yyy.181.221.woopeedoo.net.   IN  PTR woopeedoo.net
```

Comment: Is this the REAL records for the nameserver....I'm confused as to the relationship between your description.

Comment: Crossposting the identical note is frowned on in within the SE system.  Thanks for telling everybody however.

Comment: @mdpc - yes these are real records are for the ns (ip redacted) I can add the records for the domains too if reqd.

Comment: I wouldn't normally go anywhere near crossposting, but this was a tricky one.

Comment: Why is this not a real question? Just because I have provided plenty of information and you can't be bothered to read it doesn't mean I can't ask for help. It's perfectly clear what I'm asking, it's not ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and it is perfectly suited to being answered. Perhaps you should read this: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/4066/over-use-of-off-topic-closure?cb=1 It may well be referring to 'off-topic' closures but the principle of wielding power badly is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DNS for `zzokk.com` is fine:

```
zzokk.com.              38400   IN      A       127.0.0.2
zzokk.com.              38400   IN      NS      ns1.woopeedoo.net.
zzokk.com.              38400   IN      NS      ns2.woopeedoo.net.
;; Received 124 bytes from 78.129.181.221#53(78.129.181.221) in 106 ms
```

Although the actual answer is unusual because it points to a localhost IP address, which means that the HTTP site will only work when accessed from the machine actually serving it. You probably want to point this record to the actual public IP address.

The DNS for `leoponton.org` is broken however because the nameservers refuse to answer queries:

```
Host leoponton.org.home not found: 5(REFUSED)
```

Check that you have configured the correct NS records, that your DNS server software is actually running, and that the firewall allows incoming packets.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. leoponton.org failed because I rebuilt the server and only setup a vserver for zzokk.

Comment: It is certainly only serving the page from my local machine and I've been trying to solve that.

Comment: Sorted! I made the mistake of believing that Virtualmin knew what it was doing. Two big fixes were: 1. ensure that the IP for the server is the external IP not an internal one (VMin decided to use 127.0.0.2)    2. In System_Settings->Virtualmin_Config->Netwk_Settings make 'net iface for virt addresses = venet0:0

Comment: I think venet0 was the default which produces 127.0.0.2   venet0:0 will produce the external IP.