# nameserver problems with webmin/virtualmin

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, nameserver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [nameserver problems with webmin/virtualmin](https://serverfault.com/questions/460462/nameserver-problems-with-webmin-virtualmin)

I'm setting up a shiny new vps with my own nameserver. Fortunately I had a spare domain that I'm using and have registered as a nameserver.

After a struggle, I seem to have it working but when I check two test sites with intoDNS, one appears to work and the other doesn't.

With dig, neither work. The setup for the two is identical other than one being hosted with namecheap and the other with dataflame.co.uk.

The urls are:

1. http://zzokk.com
2. http://leoponton.org

The nameserver entries for the two sites were repointed 48 hours ago.

I can't figure out what the problem is. Anybody got any ideas?

This is the records file for the nameserver:

```
    $ttl 38400

    woopeedoo.net.  IN  SOA ns1.woopeedoo.net. xxx.gmail.com. (

                1356196970
                30M
                3600
                604800
                38400 )

woopeedoo.net.  IN  NS  ns1.woopeedoo.net.
woopeedoo.net.  IN  NS  ns2.woopeedoo.net.
ns1.woopeedoo.net.  IN  A   xx.yyy.181.221
ns2.woopeedoo.net.  IN  A   xx.yyy.181.221
woopeedoo.net.  IN  A   127.0.0.2
m.woopeedoo.net.woopeedoo.net.  IN  A   127.0.0.2
woopeedoo.net.  IN  MX  5 mail.woopeedoo.net.
mail.woopeedoo.net. IN  A   127.0.0.2
localhost.woopeedoo.net.    IN  A   127.0.0.1
xx.yyy.181.221.woopeedoo.net.   IN  PTR woopeedoo.net
```

Comment: @mgorven, mdpc, Michael Hampton, Ward, faker : Either it's duplication or not a valid question. Make your mind up. I did double post this and I also noted the fact in ServerFault. The reason I asked the question is because I couldn't find the answers to the same question on SE - similar, yes nut nevertheless inappropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IN A 127.N.N.N` is terrible, nightmare, delirium!!!

1. You **must** use **routable IPs** for you hosts if you want to get they reacheable from Net
2. You **must not** mix `IN PTR` and `IN A` in single zone-file (`IN PTR` will be ignored in any case)
3. You **can** doesn't hide IP of nameservers, because it's open information for domain-name
4. You **have** to use (when you can and it's applicable) zone `in-addr.arpa` for PTR records in 181.129.78 domain (currently managed by rns01.bhost.net.)